# Calling Curve smart contracts with eth_call gives unexpected results

Tags: go-ethereum, eth-call, curve

I came across a strange response of `eth_call`. I made a request to [Curve pool smart contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x9547429C0e2c3A8B88C6833B58FCE962734C0E8C) calling `get_dy(int128,int128,uint256)` function:

`curl your endpoint -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"method":"eth_call","params":[{"to": "0x9547429C0e2c3A8B88C6833B58FCE962734C0E8C", "data": "0x5e0d443f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000", "gas":"0x10000000"}, "latest"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}'`

The result I'm getting:

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e5842ae2d3b18b60000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a764000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000..."}`

Here I have a result of the func in the first 32 bytes and strange set of bytes with a lot of zero at the end.

Here the result that I expected (the same request but for another curve pool):
request:
`curl https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/19e0ddd67ba748e3a6e31340b9ca221e -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"method":"eth_call","params":[{"to": "0x4DEcE678ceceb27446b35C672dC7d61F30bAD69E", "data": "0x5e0d443f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000", "gas":"0x10000000"}, "latest"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}'`
response:
`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c20b71f8e363c1efe2beb"}`

Can anybody explain why I'm getting such strange response? What all of this bytes after the result mean?

Comment: You need to check the source and ABI of both smart contracts to see fi there are any internal changes in Curve. That's one likely explanation.